# Add a timer to online quiz that submits the quiz

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I am developing a web based system wherein user can give tests submitted by admin, the issue is i want to implement a timer that can initiate at start of the quiz and autosubmit the test as soon as it ends , need help on how do i implement read a lot of aanswers but did not help specific to my project .`

```
<span id="countdown" class="timer"></span>
<script>
var seconds = 40;
    function secondPassed() {
    var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
    }
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" +    remainingSeconds;
    if (seconds == 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Buzz Buzz";
    } else {    
        seconds--;
    }
    }
var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
</script>
```

`

Comment: refer this link for getting more details for your question https://www.edureka.co/blog/creating-an-online-quiz-application-implementing-countdown-timer/

Comment: How is your form questions? Is there a function to finish the quiz and submit? If yes you can invoke that function when seconds remaining reached 0

Comment: @SriraghavanSubramanian i have given a submit button t submit every questions answer so after the last answers submit button it submits the test and displays the result.   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q) )
{
$option=$row['option'];
$optionid=$row['optionid'];
echo'<input type="radio" name="ans" value="'.$optionid.'">'.$option.'<br /><br />';
}
echo'<br /><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;Submit</button></form></div>';